# Dual boot Ubuntu won't shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, shutdown

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS with Windows 11 in dual boot. Whenever I shutdown my Ubuntu it doesn't shutdown and is stuck at the screen attached in picture.

[image: picture]

Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Are you familiar with the command line (terminal)? Please try to shut down from a terminal `sudo poweroff` or `sudo reboot` and let us know if this works.